# Headers already sent but not sure why

Tags: node.js, express, request

I know this has been answered 1000's of times but I can not for the life of me figure out why it is trying to send headers more than once. So please if you are going to mark as duplicate, explain why it is a duplicate and where I went wrong. A link rarely is helpful without some explanation.

Okay onto my problem. I have a simple confirmation route that runs a middleware/controller when I try to resend the confirmation token a second time to replicate a user clicking a confirmation link a second time it tells me the line I noted next to is causing me to resend headers.

The token for the user is still in my DB (plan to change this) but should not matter since the line that seems to be causing the error is just checking the user profile to see if it is verified.

```
router.post('/confirmation', 
  user.confirmationPost);


exports.confirmationPost = function (req, res, next) {
    // Find a matching token
    Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token }, function (err, token) {
        if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ type: 'not-verified', message: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.' });

        // If we found a token, find a matching user
        User.findOne({ _id: token._userId }, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ message: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });
            if (user.isVerified) return res.status(400).send({ message: 'This user has already been verified.' }); // THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR

            // Verify and save the user
            user.isVerified = true;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message }); }
                res.redirect(`${config.siteURL}/dash`);
            });
        });
    });
    next();
};
```

**Error message**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my issue, the issue was `next()` near the end, it was getting called after the res.send/json which was trying to pass/set the headers again.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use the new await/async, the callback style is error-prone,
difficulty to arrange async control follow.

Express framework is callback style, you can use https://github.com/tj/co inside
your handler for use await/async, but finally http://koajs.com/ is better.

Comment: I am still learning promises as I was told best to learn them before I do async await. So I will get there in time but for now callbacks are what I am using just because they are what I know and I want to release this sooner than later. Time later to rewrite the program to newer methods I have learned. Maybe you could provide an example of how I would rewrite this to use async/await so I could see?

Comment: Use util.promisify https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original to wrap callback style api to promise, use https://github.com/tj/co to driver all promise/async/await style api in your callback style framework. You can refactor your old callback style project slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you figured out your problem, feel free to mark your response as the correct answer!

I went ahead and wrote your code snippet above using ES7's async/await syntax. While the code may look longer, it's meant to be easier to understand. I also expanded all the return functions and added comments, which contributed to the length.

```
/*
 * Notice how the keyword `async` is in front of the arrow function. 
 * This tags the function as asynchronous and returns a promise. 
 * It also allows us to use the `await` keyword which waits for the function 
 * to return whatever follows the await keyword. Only after it returns will 
 * the function continue.
 */ 
exports.confirmationPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    // The await keyword here makes sure that Token.findOne() returns (resolves/rejects promise) before continuing the function.
    // However, this DOES NOT mean that the program hangs, as it would for a synchronous function. 
    // Other functions can run while this instance of the function waits for Token.findOne() to return.
    let token = await Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token });

    // Once Token.findOne returns, you have access to a then callback.
    token.then((err, token) => {
        if (!token) { 
            // While this is completely fine, I suggest you use next() and pass in an error obj to it and let your middleware handle the return of the error to the client.
            return res.status(400).send({ 
                type: 'not-verified', 
                message: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.' 
            });
        }

        // Once again, we use await to wait for User.findOne() to return.
        let user = await User.findOne({ _id: token._userId });

        // Once User.findOne returns, you have access to a then callback.
        user.then((err, user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).send({ 
                    message: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' 
                });
            }
            if (user.isVerified) {
                return res.status(400).send({ 
                    message: 'This user has already been verified.' 
                }); 
            }

            // Verify and save the user
            user.isVerified = true;

            // You can simply chain the then callback instead of making a new variable.
            user.save().then(err => {
                if (err) { 
                    return res.status(500).send({ 
                        message: err.message 
                    }); 
                }
                res.redirect(`${config.siteURL}/dash`);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Check out these two links below that will really hit the nail on the head when it comes to using promises and async/await with Node and Mongo.

1. https://medium.com/@rossbulat/using-promises-async-await-with-mongodb-613ed8243900
2. http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/cleaner-code-in-nodejs-with-async-await-mongoose-calls-example

Comment: I'm also assuming you are using Mongo based on your function calls in your code. And since Mongo functions now support await/async, you don't have to use any fancy libraries to wrap your Mongo calls!

Comment: Thanks for the code example, and for marking my answer right, SO limits you on that, it takes 72 hours I think before I can mark it right, so about another 12 hours for me. I'll make sure to read those links, TY

Comment: @JoshKirby, great! Let me know if you have any questions. Also, if you found my answer helpful, feel free to upvote it too. :)